# Where are the 'Contributions - Receipt (on-line) templates stored?

Tags: civicontribute, receipts

I want to customise on line receipts, but am struggling to make a start. I can see the on line receipt in the Message Templates - 'Contributions - Receipt (on-line)' but can't find where the other files associated with this template are located. The documentation doesn't seem to explain this at all. 
 I want to make the receipt look very different from the default.  Also if any one has some customised receipt templates they can share, that would be great too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the code that uses the template?  If so, look at CRM/Contribute/BAO/ContributionPage.php and look for 'contribution_online_receipt' which is the template name for 'Contributions - Receipt (on-line)'.

Unless you want to pass different data to the template, you should just need to edit the template at `Administer > Communications > Message Templates > System Workflow Messages`

If you change the templates you might find this extension useful when you need to reconcile future core changes with your changes: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/msgtplhelper

And if you're making your templates look better, try this: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/prettyworkflowmessages